# Animate image inside scrolling div

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

For the last week I have been trying to find a way to get a div/image to animate inside of a scrollable div. I have tried [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) (With [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)) and [aos.js](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/), neither of which will work inside a container div I have been told.

I tried [Waypoints](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/05/31/scroll-anmiation-css-waypoints/) and after trying [This Solution](http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery/) and having no luck I'm starting to think it's not possible but I would LOVE to be proven wrong. I would like to use animate.css as it has animations I like and are easy to deal with but if that's not an option so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned what kind of animation you want. But this might get you started with scrolling div animation: (just scroll down to the bottom)

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

```css
body {
    height:1600px;
}
.bottomMenu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work on the page I am working on. If I don't put display:none the image appears very tiny. If I do put it, it closes the gap and nothing happens. The image still doesn't animate regardless. You can see what I am working with here - http://smappdooda.com/new/about2.php

Comment: @Bizzaro Try binding `.content` div instead of `document` to the animation. Ex: `$(".content").scroll(function () .......rest of code same`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was out of town. No change it seems.